# How to recover an overwritten SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, disaster-recovery

We have SQL Server Standard Edition with several databases. We backup via a Windows Task that executes the [`sp_BackupDatabases` procedure](http://web.archive.org/web/20150330070326/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698).

We have a case where a database got replaced by a backup from 2 days ago by mistake.

Unfortunately the connection to the NAS crashed, so the last 4 days, there where no backups made.

Since a backup was restored over the current database, there is no transaction log we could use to manually undo the changes.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get a version of the database before the database was restored? For example, does `sp_BackupDatabases`  make a local temp backup and moves it then, so that this temp backup could be still available?

Comment: You're only as good as your last backup and, if my math is right, the last backup you have is from 4 days ago.  Any chance your systems guys took a VM snapshot or some sort of backup of the OS and files?

Comment: Unfortunately not. =(

Comment: Then the answer is no. This is why we validate our backups (e.g. restore them on another system), don't rely on a single point of failure (NAS), deal with those immediately instead of 4 days later, and limit who is able to restore databases on critical systems (to minimize the chance for mistakes like this).

Answer (score 2):

As far as SQL native backups are concerned, you can only restore to the last good backup that you have which is 4 days ago.  So, unfortunately, from a SQL server backup perspective you may have lost 4 days worth of data.

That being said, if this is a VM (HyperV, VMWare, etc) and there are snapshots, you may be in luck and your systems guys may be able to get the information back.

Comment: There may be OS backups even if not a VM, too, however in either case the mdf/ldf files may not have been backed up in a way that they are viable (I always warn customers not to rely on snapshots or other file-level copies as "backups").

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a snapshot as well.. :(